# Good Transliteration of the name "Chloe"

Tags: translation, names

I'm trying to translate the name Chloe into Chinese that would be meaningful and sound the same as it does in English.

> The name Chloe is a Greek baby name. In Greek the meaning of the name
>   Chloe is: Green shoot. Fresh blooming.

I have come up with "草怡". Does that work as a transliteration of the name or does that name not seem right? I don't want to pick anything that would have a negative colloquialism.

Comment: "草怡" is quite good, need to adjust with 時辰八字?

Comment: user suggestion 克略，web search yields 希拉克略 Heraclius, confirming characters have been used in transliteration

Comment: 草 is not very common in Chinese names, but it is not bad either. However, note that people recently like to use 草, 艹, or 操 on the Internet to replace  肏 (cao4), which means f**k.

Comment: comment #2: transliteration understood as 译音、音译 transcription of phonetic symbols ，（as in transliteration key 转写法）

Comment: slightly different transliteration in 法汉词典：http://fayufaguo.com/Chloe Chloe nom.
克罗伊

Comment: Perhaps, OP doesn't know the exact meaning of transliteration.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your answers. Part of my effort is to keep the same or similar meaning as the original name. I am not interested in just matching the sounds. Thanks!

Comment: regarding use of character 伊 note John Doe：约翰·多伊 as in 丹尼跟着抬着编号为＃1——1／1／5约翰·多伊的担架来到县属装卸平台。。。http://www.baiyun.net/detective/wccs01.html

Answer (score 1):

The "Hit Girl" actress is 克蘿伊 --

https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%A7%91%E6%B4%9B%C2%B7%E8%8E%AB%E7%91%9E%E5%85%B9

```
   克蘿伊·格雷丝·摩蕾茲 （英语：Chloë Grace Moretz，1997年2月10日－），美國女演員，.......
```

This page https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloe shows others with the same 克蘿伊, which seems the most common Chinese rendering of the name.

```
 克蘿伊‧安格紐，愛爾蘭歌手，女性合唱團體天使女伶（Celtic Woman）的最年輕成員。
 克蘿伊·布莉姬（Chloe Bridges），美國女演員、歌手。
 克蘿伊·瓊斯（Chloe Jones），美國女性色情演員。
 克蘿伊·馬歇爾（Chloe Marshall），英國大尺碼模特兒，2008年薩里小姐冠軍，英國小姐亞軍
```

Comment: top answer covers full names with English language last names, French Chloe has accent aigu on e, Chinese transliteration thus reflects language difference of originals

Answer (score 1):

For a girl，柯萝翊，柯萝奕，柯萝漪

For a boy, 柯罗逸，柯罗毅，柯罗驿

Answer (score 0):

**克洛伊**

The TV show *24* has a character whose name is also Chloe, her name is usually transliterated as 克洛伊.

A quick [Baidu search](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=24%E5%B0%8F%E6%97%B6%20%E5%85%8B%E6%B4%9B%E4%BC%8A&rsv_spt=1&rsv_iqid=0xacfd0e2400012f80&issp=1&f=3&rsv_bp=1&rsv_idx=2&ie=utf-8&rqlang=cn&tn=baiduhome_pg&rsv_enter=1&inputT=3771&rsv_t=f45cNth6Gciz%2F0ft05WuQOoGzyvrl2%2FnrfAeiufouLET%2F7240PgTl%2FFFz6fMnySPI0Dc&rsv_sug3=16&rsv_sug1=12&rsv_sug7=100&oq=24%E5%B0%8F%E6%97%B6%20chloe&rsv_pq=e8a61b710001194f&rsv_sug2=0&prefixsug=24%E5%B0%8F%E6%97%B6%20kelu&rsp=0&rsv_sug4=4308) returns the following:

> 为什么看完反恐24小时那么喜欢克洛伊?
>
> 24小时大结局,杰克与克洛伊的告白,悲壮得简直可以用荡气回肠来形
>
> 爱死24小时的克洛伊了。

Results for [克洛伊](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E5%85%8B%E6%B4%9B%E4%BC%8A&rsv_spt=1&rsv_iqid=0xacfd0e2400012f80&issp=1&f=8&rsv_bp=1&rsv_idx=2&ie=utf-8&rqlang=cn&tn=baiduhome_pg&rsv_enter=1&inputT=131160&rsv_t=1065QBM0tgjUydCncrjaAZwTFyNSZFNnh3QaZto4BxmWcKq%2FRN%2B7Gkj9dUheWuwNQkJz&oq=24%E5%B0%8F%E6%97%B6%20%E5%85%8B%E6%B4%9B%E4%BC%8A&rsv_pq=d0f4ddc300012797&rsv_sug3=21&rsv_sug1=20&rsv_sug7=100&rsv_sug2=0&rsv_sug4=133589) also return a lot of Chloé/Chloe:

> Chloé官方网站 / 名牌服装、手袋、香氛官网
>
> 克洛伊CHLOE DVD中字_土豆_高清视频在线观看
>
> 三亚婚纱摄影_三亚【克洛伊】婚纱摄影工作室_海外婚纱摄影_三亚...

Answer (score 0):

chloe 可怡
This is most suitable for a girl in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

可蕾.

- 可(ke3): able, becoming, agreeable
- 蕾(lei3): bud, bloom

Both are frequent female name characters.

The only downside is that they all go the third tone like down-up-down-up which can be mouthful for a name, but you can substitute 可 with 珂, another frequent female name character. The latter sounds better, but the meaning could be a bit off.

珂(ke1): (white) jade.